# Refresh remote Git branches in Android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, refresh, remote-branch

There is a new branch in the remote repository, but it does not appear in the git branches in android studio. How can I refresh that list to show the new branch?

I have tried `git branch -r` 
but new branch is not showing in the list.

Answer (score 108):

In your Android Studio menu bar, click on `VCS > Git > Fetch`

Check the image:

[image: Git Fetch in Android Studio]

Comment: Would be nice if they just named it "Refresh remote" or something similar.

Comment: Theres no Git option there.

Comment: @ralphgabb If VCS is enabled, the option is available in the Menu bar. I have updated the answer and added image in it. Please check the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using `VCS (from menu)` then click on `Git` and then on `Fetch`.
Alternatively, you can use `git fetch --all`

Answer (score 3):

Try using [git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) or use `git fetch --all`