# Git could not see remote branches in android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I have only basic knowledge in git.

I only **cloned single branch** from my remote using command line and following command (the repository has multiple branches at the time of cloning)

```
git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch
```

I am able to do all git operations using my android-studio IDE vcs support to the cloned branch. Now I want to switch my remote branch but my android-studio IDE not showing the remote branches. It is showing only one branch that i used to clone. From the searches I had I checked the following solutions but doesn't work.

[Refresh remote Git branches in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362422/refresh-remote-git-branches-in-android-studio)

How can I get the list of remote branches without cloning the master branch from the scratch?

Comment: you need to fetch  the branches first
`git fetch <remote> <rbranch>:<lbranch> `
also i recommended to use Source tree if you are a beginner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only seeing one branch, because you used `--single-branch`

From the [git documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

> **--[no-]single-branch**
>
> Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the --branch option or the primary branch remote’s HEAD points at. Further fetches into the resulting repository will only update the remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning. If the HEAD at the remote did not point at any branch when --single-branch clone was made, no remote-tracking branch is created.

To undo this:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git fetch origin
```

To add a single branch:

```
git remote set-branches --add origin [remote-branch]
git fetch origin [remote-branch]:[local-branch]
```